# Sub Expression using Read-Host

Tags: powershell, scripting

Can someone please explain to me why this doesn't work?

```
Get-Item "'\\$(Read-Host 'Specify Computer')\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\winword.exe'"

"'\\$(Read-Host 'Specify Computer')\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\winword.exe'" | Get-Item
```

Write-Host behaves exactly as I would expect...

```
Write-Host "'\\$(Read-Host 'Specify Computer')\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\winword.exe'"

"'\\$(Read-Host 'Specify Computer')\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\winword.exe'" | Write-Host
```

Also, if I manually provide string it works fine.

```
 Get-Item "'\\computer\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\winword.exe'"

"'\\computer\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\winword.exe'" | Get-Item
```

Any idea as to why Get-Item wants to append the target location to the current location in this circumstance?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work for me if you remove the nested single quotes:

```
Get-Item "\\$(Read-Host 'Specify Computer')\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\winword.exe"

"\\$(Read-Host 'Specify Computer')\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\winword.exe" | Get-Item
```

If not, can you add the error you are getting to your question?

Comment: This worked! I swear I tried using just a single pair of quotes initially and I got an error about path not found because of spaces in path.

Comment: Maybe you tried just single quotes? Single quotes `'` don't typically resolve variables and such, while double quotes `"` typically do.